# Infinite Loop: keep printing a single line

Tags: loops, go, infinite-loop

There's an infinite loop that will call a function() every 5 seconds. According to certain conditions, the function() will either print `OK` or `Not Ok`.

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    
    for {
        dummy()
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

func dummy() {
    resp, _ := http.Get("dummy.test.com")
    
    if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
        fmt.Println("OK")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not OK.")
    }   
}
```

Instead of printing:

```
OK
OK
OK
...
```

or vice versa, I want a single line to be printed, like so:

```
OK
```

And when the function() re-executes after 5 seconds, I want the data that's about to be printed to replace the previous printed data on the same line.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: You are looking for a terminal API instead of a log library. Google ncurses (which will give you for example https://github.com/rthornton128/goncurses)

Comment: Already got the answer. Thank anyway Norb.

Comment: please check the resp could be nil (you are not evaluating a possible error). I suggest you to do as follow  `if resp != nil && resp.StatusCode == 200 {`

Comment: It's just for the sake of an example. I would never share the real thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to print the carriage return character `\r` for this which you can't to with `Println`. Suggest using `Printf` instead

```
fmt.Printf("\r%s", "OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    
    for {
        result := dummy()
        fmt.Println(result)
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

func dummy() string {
    resp, _ := http.Get("dummy.test.com")
    
    if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
        return "OK"
    } else {
        return "Not Ok!"
    }
    
}
```